# how can i set the value of a variable be accessed by any method in a PHP Class?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to use 2 methods in my class.

the class structure looks something similar to this

```
class Test extends Something
{
    private $dir;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    private function check_theme()
    {
        // do some checking here
        $this->dir = // outcome of the checking
    }

    public function load_theme()
    {
        $this->check_theme();
    }

    public function load_file()
    {
        $this->dir . $path . $to . $file
    }
}
```

ok so now, this only works if I run something like

```
$test = new Test();

$test->load_theme();
$test->load_file();
```

but now I have a different method that I want to access directly but I really want for that method to already know what the value of `$dir` is.

so if I used `$test->load_file();` It would load the file because the value of `$dir` was already set by `$test->check_theme();`

Comment: private $dir = $GLOBALS['dir'] ? just a thought .. never tried it

Comment: The code you've posted can *already* access `$dir` from other methods. I can't tell what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I get your question properly. I suggest to keep a flag for when the value of `$dir` is set.

Here before using the `$dir` value, we do the test to ensure its value is set. If not we call `$load_theme()` which calls `check_theme()` just in the same sequence as you showed in your question.

```
class Test extends Something
{
    private $dir;
    private $file_loaded;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->file_loaded = false;

    }

    private function check_theme()
    {
        // do some checking here
        $this->dir = // outcome of the checking
    }

    public function load_theme()
    {
        $this->check_theme();
        $this->file_loaded = true;   
    }

    public function load_file()
    {
        if (!$this->file_loaded)
            $this->load_theme();            
        $this->dir . $path . $to . $file
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, ya something like that might help in the checking. I was just wondering if I would be able to access the $dir from any method without needing to first run the check_theme(); method over and over again